# Strange Visual Studio Behavior: Very long execution time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, execution-time

I have noticed that some code takes a very long time to execute in Visual Studio as opposed to compiling it manually with CL and running the executable.

Here is an example of code which exhibits this behavior:

```
int DP[MAX][MAX];
class CartInSupermarketEasy {
public:
int calc(int N, int K) {
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i) {
        DP[0][i] = 0;
        DP[1][i] = 1;
        DP[i][0] = i;
    }

    for (int n = 1; n <= N; ++n) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= K; ++k) {
            int min_res = N;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
                for (int j = 0; j < k; ++j) {
                    int curr_res = max(DP[n - i][k - 1 - j], DP[i][j]) + 1;
                    min_res = min(curr_res, min_res);
                }
            }
            DP[n][k] = min(min_res, DP[n - 1][k] + 1);
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << elapsed_secs << '\n';
    return DP[N][K];
    }
} CI;

int main(){
    cout << CI.calc(100,100) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

When run in VS2013, the function calc takes about 13.5 seconds to calculate the answer. In VS2012, this goes down to 3.5 seconds. However, when compiled manually with CL (or any other compiler that I've tried ), the executable returns an answer in .4 seconds.

How can this discrepancy be explained, and how can I make VS execute on par with manual compilation/execution?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you comparing *release* vs. *release* and also with the same optimization levels (or equivalent)?

Comment: Are you timing the Visual Studio versions with or without the IDE?

Comment: Yea I was actually not comparing to release rather to debug build. Thank you, and thanks to Pawel who commented earlier but I don't see his comment anymore.

Comment: Are you using the `std::max` function or one you wrote yourself?  Same with the `min` function.  The compiler may have optimized versions of these functions.

Comment: By the way, are you safely accessing your arrays?  When `k` is less than or equal to  `j`, you will have a negative index when using the `max` function.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Using std::max/min. You are saying it's better to use the built-in one instead of one I write myself? The inner loop has `j<k` as the entrance condition.

Comment: Any version of VS after 2008 is slow.  If you want the actual time taken to run, pop up a MessageBox after main so you can start timing when you click on the button.  The discrepancy is the time taken to set up the system for debugging.  It needs to load up the .pdbs and tie up the symbols with the ones in the .sdf file.  If you have included iostream,   there are a few hundred symbols to tie up, even though most of them are not used.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews Interestingly, using my own min/max functions, improved performance x10 in Debug and x2 in Release

Comment: [Optimizing Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)

Comment: From that page: While writing an application, a programmer will recompile and test often, and so compilation must be fast. This is one reason most optimizations are deliberately avoided during the test/debugging phase. Also, program code is usually "stepped through" (see Program animation) using a symbolic debugger, and optimizing transformations, particularly those that reorder code, can make it difficult to relate the output code with the line numbers in the original source code. This can confuse both the debugging tools and the programmers using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I was running using the "Debug" configuration instead of "Release". Changing it the build configuration to "Release" has solved the problem. Interestingly, it runs about 4 times faster than manual compilation/execution now.

Update:
As pointed out in the comments, a lot of the slowdown was caused due to use of std::min and std::max functions. Switching to custom made min/max functions, sped up the execution by a factor of 3-4. Here is an article confirming this observation: [std::min causing three times slowdown](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/11/24/stdmin-causing-three-times-slowdown-on-vc/)

Comment: I don't know what computer you're using but your program takes roughly .1 seconds on mine using VS2013/Win32/Debug.

Comment: Really? Very strange. That's about what I am getting in Release now, but Debug is still giving me 13.4 secs.

Comment: I tried doing that, but I don't know how to understand from the report why it's taking so long in Debug.

Comment: Are you using the [Performance Wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)? If not you could still upload the report and we will see what causes the slowdowns.

Comment: Interesting: I replaced the std::min/max functions with custom made ones, and the run time in Debug has been reduced x10 to 1.46 sec, which is still x10 more than release run time. Here is a link to the performance report (still using the std::min/max) [Work150211.vsp](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzZo3mTuII-pbE4tMTIxaWJNZ0E/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Here is another question: When running CI.calc(300,300), the program returns an answer in 6 seconds (Release). If I understand correctly, the run time of the program should be: (300^4)/8 which is about 10^9 ops. Isn't that a bit too fast for so many ops?

Comment: Yes that is another question and it should be treated as one and not as a comment. Apart from that, your uploaded report reveals that the slowdowns are in fact caused by std::min/std::max. Here a [tip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd551466.aspx) on how to read those reports. You can then open the resulting .vsps file in VS.

Comment: I see, thanks for looking at it. Still, even with my own min/max, getting 1.6 secs in Debug for the calc(100,100), where as in Release it takes about 0.04

Comment: Thank, My video render (ffmpeg & directx) on debug take 130ms-140ms to convert a frame. But when i run exe on non-debug it take only ~10ms.